# Mobile data usage on smartphone when NordVPN is turned on

Tags: mobile-data, vpn

I've recently started to use NordVPN on smartphone as I need to spend a lot of time in public networks.

However, it is only 5th August and I have already got a data warning that I have used 2GB of mobile data.

Which makes me think that NordVPN does not change the "carrier" network automatically, when I switch from LTE (4G) to some WiFi (office or home).

I've contacted NordVPN support team, they told me that all traffic is accounted for an actual app (e. g., Firefox) and NordVPN. The problem is that the mobile plan provider somehow adds these two traffics. I use an Android phone.

How to solve this problem? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could, potentially, manage your traffic by following a couple of rules:

1. When you are on the move, i.e. using mobile data
   a. Turn **OFF**  Wi-Fi
   b. Turn **OFF** VPN
   c. **Enable** Mobile Data
2. When you are expecting to use an unsecured WiFi *(e.g. Internet Café, Airport)*
   a. **DISABLE** Mobile Data
   b. Turn **ON** VPN
   c. Turn **ON** Wi-Fi

The order that these are done in is important. This does, *of course*, assume that you do trust your carriers internet access to be *reasonably* private.

You could potentially automate with something like If This Then That or you may be able to find an app that lets you have a button to toggle these settings.

Comment: Yes, thank you. A little bit involving procedure, but it seems the only option.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue here that NordVPN do not recognise. From Jan - Oct this year I had adequate mobile data. In November my mobile data consumption rocketed up. In December the NordVPN app consumed most of my mobile data allowance, so I turned mobile data off. I contacted NordVPN, they have not got a clue. To me something in the App is consuming data and this error has emerged in Q4. I'm going to get myself another VPN that pays a bit more attention to it's customer. I would recommend that you do the same.

When I look at the mobile data usage log for Nov and Dec, NordVPN is the number one mobile data consumer.